# Display non-resultant row SQL (groupby - count)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with a query (MS SQL Server) and I want to know if it is possible to do something like the following and how to do it properly.

This is the query:

```
select numTenants, count(codSite) numSites
from (select case count(st1.name) when 0 then '0T'
                       when 1 then '1T' 
                       when 2 then '2T' 
                       when 3 then '3T'
                       when 4 then '4T'
                       else 'More than 4T' end numTenants, os1.siteCode as codSite
    from fl_OperativeSite os1 left join fl_SiteTenant st1
        on st1.fkOperativeSite=os1.pkOperativeSite
    where  os1.siteType='A' and os1.externalInfrastructure=2
    group by os1.siteCode) groups
group by numTenants
order by numTenants
```

and this is the result:

```
numTenants     numSites
   1T             2957
   2T              553
   3T             1503
   4T              423
More than 4T       131
```

Because obviously there is not a "site" with 0 as numTenants.

What I wanted to ask is: is there a way to have the result shown as below?

```
numTenants     numSites
   0T                0
   1T             2957
   2T              553
   3T             1503
   4T              423
More than 4T       131
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can use outer join and replace NULL result with "0".

Comment: Do you use these number ranges often? Then you should have a table for them containing the text (e.g. 'More than 4T'), the range (e.g. from = 5, to = null) and the sortkey (e.g. 5). This would simplify such queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your own query is working fine.
create one table variable.

```
declare @tbl table(numTenants varchar(50))
insert into @tbl values ('0T'), ('1T'),('2T'),('3T'),('4T'),('More than 4T')

;With CTE As
(
 select numTenants, count(codSite) numSites
from (select case count(st1.name) when 0 then '0T'
                       when 1 then '1T' 
                       when 2 then '2T' 
                       when 3 then '3T'
                       when 4 then '4T'
                       else 'More than 4T' end numTenants, os1.siteCode as codSite
    from fl_OperativeSite os1 left join fl_SiteTenant st1
        on st1.fkOperativeSite=os1.pkOperativeSite
    where  os1.siteType='A' and os1.externalInfrastructure=2
    group by os1.siteCode) groups
group by numTenants
order by numTenants
)

select a.numTenants,isnull(s.numSites,0) numSites from @tbl A 
left join CTE S on a.numTenants=s.numTenants
```

Answer (score 3):

This is quite simple: Select all "numbers" and outer join your query:

```
select numbers.str, results.numSites
from 
(
    select '0T' as str union all
    select '1T' union all
    select '2T' union all
    select '3T' union all
    select '4T' union all
    select 'More than 4T'
) numbers
left join
(
  select numTenants, count(codSite) numSites
  from 
  (
    select 
      case count(st1.name) 
        when 0 then '0T'
        when 1 then '1T' 
        when 2 then '2T' 
        when 3 then '3T'
        when 4 then '4T'
        else 'More than 4T' 
      end numTenants,
      os1.siteCode as codSite
    from fl_OperativeSite os1 
    left join fl_SiteTenant st1
           on st1.fkOperativeSite=os1.pkOperativeSite
    where os1.siteType='A' and os1.externalInfrastructure=2
    group by os1.siteCode) groups
  group by numTenants
) results on results.numTenants = numbers.str
order by numbers.str;
```